How can I stop having white background after switching off scroll bars in CDialog?
My dialog (in resource editor) has the resizing and maximize/minimize switched on.
But, if I detect that I don't need this functionality because their display is of a sufficient size I want to switch them off.
So I did this:
int CResizingDialog::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    const CDC* pDC = GetDC();
    if (pDC != nullptr)
    {
        const int iHorz = pDC->GetDeviceCaps(HORZRES);
        const int iVert = pDC->GetDeviceCaps(VERTRES);

        bool showHorz = true;
        bool showVert = true;

        if (lpCreateStruct->cx < iHorz)
        {
            // Remove the WS_HSCROLL style to disable the horizontal scroll bar
            ModifyStyle(WS_HSCROLL, 0);
            showHorz = false;
        }

        if (lpCreateStruct->cy < iVert)
        {
            // Remove the WS_VSCROLL style to disable the vertical scroll bar
            ModifyStyle(WS_VSCROLL, 0);
            showVert = false;
        }

        if (!showHorz && !showVert && m_bModalWindow)
        {
            // Remove the WS_THICKFRAME style rtc to disable resizing
            ModifyStyle(WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, 0);
        }
    }

    if (__super::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    return 0;
}

It works, but look:

I now have two white rectangles on the right / bottom where I switched off the scroll bars. How do we address this?

Well, you sized your dialog originally based on the dialog resource (scrollbars and thickframe included) and later you removed them, hence the empty area. A solution could be to resize the frame, reducing it by the scrollbars and thickframe width/height (check GetSystemMetrics()), rather than the client (if you still want its size to be determined by the resource). I would also rather try to use the PreCreateWindow() member instead, ie set the styles before the window is created.

@ConstantineGeorgiou PreCreateWindow does not seem to be triggered for CDialog.

I needed to make a call to SetWindowPos, like this:
int CResizingDialog::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    const CDC* pDC = GetDC();
    if (pDC != nullptr)
    {
        const auto style = GetStyle();
        const int iHorz = pDC->GetDeviceCaps(HORZRES);
        const int iVert = pDC->GetDeviceCaps(VERTRES);

        bool showHorz{true};
        bool showVert{true};
        bool redrawWindow{false};

        bool hasHorzScrollBar{ false };
        if (style & WS_HSCROLL)
        {
            hasHorzScrollBar = true;
            // Do we need to switch off the horizontal scroll?
            if (lpCreateStruct->cx < iHorz)
            {
                // Remove the WS_HSCROLL style to disable the horizontal scroll bar
                ModifyStyle(WS_HSCROLL, 0);
                showHorz = false;
                redrawWindow = true;
            }
        }

        bool hasVertScrollBar{ false };
        if (style & WS_VSCROLL)
        {
            hasVertScrollBar = true;
            // Do we need to switch off the vertical scroll?
            if (lpCreateStruct->cy < iVert)
            {
                // Remove the WS_VSCROLL style to disable the vertical scroll bar
                ModifyStyle(WS_VSCROLL, 0);
                showVert = false;
                redrawWindow = true;
            }
        }

        if ((hasHorzScrollBar && !showHorz) &&
            (hasVertScrollBar && !showVert) && m_bModalWindow)
        {
            // Remove the WS_THICKFRAME style etc to disable resizing
            ModifyStyle(WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, WS_DLGFRAME);
            redrawWindow = true;
        }

        // Apply new frame styles (important for cache update)
        if (redrawWindow)
        {
            // SM_CXSIZEFRAME thickness horizontal
            // SM_CYSIZEFRAME thickness vertical
            // SM_CXVSCROLL thickness vertical
            // SM_CYHSCROLL thickness horizontal

            int scrollVert{ 0 };
            if (hasVertScrollBar && !showVert)
            {
                scrollVert = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL);
            }

            int scrollHorz{ 0 };
            if (hasHorzScrollBar && !showHorz)
            {
                scrollHorz = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYHSCROLL);
            }

            SetWindowPos(nullptr,
                lpCreateStruct->x,
                lpCreateStruct->y,
                lpCreateStruct->cx - scrollVert,
                lpCreateStruct->cy - scrollHorz, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
        }
    }

    if (__super::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    return 0;
}

